# Why 0010 in javascript is equal to 8?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

i wrote from 001 to 0010 and much more digit like this that started with "00" in chrome console and Fire Fox even in IE and get this result.

[image]

why 0010 is not equal to  10 ?
or why 0020 is not equal to 20 ? and it is "16".

Comment: It's because it's an octal.

Comment: `why 0010 is not equal to 10 ? or why 0020 is not equal to 20 ? and it is "16".` Because those numbers are to base 8(octal).

Comment: Read about the [radix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

Comment: @adeneo - I thought 'octagon' was funnier :)

Comment: @MartinJames - tomato, tomato, same thing, it has something to do with eight !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A leading zero indicates that a number should be interpreted as octal.

Thus `10` interpreted as octal is equal to `8` in decimal.

For more information refer to [MDN on number literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Integers).

Answer (score 4):

"Numeric constants are considered octal if they are preceded by a zero, and are considered hexadecimal if they are preceded by a zero and and x (0x)." (as explained [here](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/The_Complete_Javascript_Number_Reference))

008 is not considered octal because it contains "8" which is not an octal number. 0010 is in fact an octal number and equals 8.

Answer (score 3):

Number literals in Javascript can be entered in different bases -

a leading zero means the number is the number is in octal base (only digits 0-7)  so 010 is the same as:  one times 8 + zero

the literal 0x10 is in hexadecimal (base 16) so equals to:  one times 16 + zero) = 16

see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals

Answer (score 3):

Because the leading 0 represents an [Octal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) number system. Likewise, if you had typed 0x010 it would equal to 16, since 0x is prefix for [Hexadecimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) number system.